# Apache commons config: Generate configuration file from defaults

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I want to distribute my application in one jar. That means that I do not want to ship any external files with it, that also includes that I do not want to ship the default configuration file with my project.

I could for sure build the basic XML structure with a implementation of JDOM2 or copy it out of the classpath onto the file system, but is there a out-of-the-box variant implemented by Commons Configuration?

I have only found online documentation that explains reading and handling already existing configuration files.

I would imagine this code taking in a number of Key -> Value Pairs and then generating a new config, is this possible?

Please do not offer me any alternatives to a XML file, please answer this question specifically to the implementation I asked about. If you know about any, you can suggest a alternative to Commons Configuration that does what I need to do.

Comment: Did my answer help in an way?

Comment: @JonasWolf oops, thank you, I used it and forgot about it. Thank you.

Comment: Thx, I was just curious. I am happy that my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about, e.g.?

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration();
config.addProperty("test.dir[@name]", "C:\\Temp\\");
config.addProperty("test.dir[@name]", "D:\\Data\\");
config.setFilename("yourfilename.xml");
config.save();
```

See all known implementing classes of: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/FileConfiguration.html

And https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/XMLConfiguration.html for an example.